# Haxe Iteration of defining variables

Tags: xml, iteration, haxe

I have a chunk of code that is parsing xml into variables. On one of the variables, there will never be more than 12 but there may be less. I am trying to define each of these variables multiple times a second. However I only need them defined if they have a variable because right now, if there is less than 12 variables, the program crashes. Right now this code below works, but only if there is 12 values present in my xml document. How do I itterate this code so I don't have a list of "if != null" statements?

```
var _vol1 = (ipts[0].volume);
var _vol2 = (ipts[1].volume);
....
....
var _vol12 = (ipts[11].volume);
```

This code works when 12 values are in my xml document but crashes if there is less than 12 which sometimes might be the case.

How do I structure the code to define/redefine the variable only if there is a value and is not null? This what what needs to be iterated????

```
If ((ipts[0].volume) != null ){
    var _vol1 = (ipts[0].volume);
}
```

I researched on the Haxe website but wasnt sure where this is applicable. My syntax and programming is not the greatest. Thanks for the help. Sorry if this is a bad question.

UPDATE: Here is my complete code as of now. It doesn't crash but its not defining the volume variables anymore now that I added the if statements

```
var xml = Xml.parse(_vMixData);

// wrap the xml for fast access
var data = new haxe.xml.Fast(xml.firstElement());

//Getting the data from inputs (here we are getting the xml node 'inputs', which contain two 'input' nodes, as per your sample xml file.
var inputs = data.node.inputs;
var ipts = new Array<VInput>();

for (input in inputs.nodes.input) {
    var ipt = new VInput();
    if (input.has.state) { 
       ipt.state = input.att.state;
       ipt.value = input.innerHTML; 
           }
    if (input.has.volume) {
        ipt.volume = Std.parseInt(input.att.volume);
          }
    if (input.has.muted) {
        ipt.muted = Std.string(input.att.muted);
          }
    ipt.value = input.innerHTML;          
    ipts.push(ipt);
}

var overlays = data.node.overlays;
var ovlys = new Array<VOverlay>();
for (overlay in overlays.nodes.overlay) {
    var ovly = new VOverlay();
    if (overlay.has.number) { 
        ovly.number = Std.parseInt(overlay.att.number);
    }
    ovly.value = overlay.innerHTML;
    ovlys.push(ovly);
}

//Defines variables based on returned information from vMix
var _fadeToBlack:Bool = data.node.fadeToBlack.innerHTML == "True" ? true : false;

var _version = data.node.version.innerHTML;
var _record:Bool = data.node.recording.innerHTML == "True" ? true : false;
var _external:Bool = data.node.external.innerHTML == "True" ? true : false;
var _stream:Bool = data.node.streaming.innerHTML == "True" ? true : false;
var _active:Int = Std.parseInt(data.node.active.innerHTML);
var _preview:Int = Std.parseInt(data.node.preview.innerHTML);

var _overlay1 = (ovlys[0].value);
var _overlay2 = (ovlys[1].value);
var _overlay3 = (ovlys[2].value);
var _overlay4 = (ovlys[3].value);
var _input1state = (ipts[0].state);


if (ipts[0].volume != null ){
var _vol1 = (ipts[0].volume);
}
if (ipts[1].volume != null ){
var _vol2 = (ipts[1].volume);
}
if (ipts[2].volume != null ){
var _vol3 = (ipts[2].volume);
}
if (ipts[3].volume != null ){
var _vol4 = (ipts[3].volume);
}
if (ipts[4].volume != null ){
var _vol5 = (ipts[4].volume);
}
if (ipts[5].volume != null ){
var _vol6 = (ipts[5].volume);
}
if (ipts[6].volume != null ){
var _vol7 = (ipts[6].volume);
}
if (ipts[7].volume != null ){
var _vol8 = (ipts[7].volume);
}
if (ipts[8].volume != null ){
var _vol9 = (ipts[8].volume);
}
if (ipts[9].volume != null ){
var _vol10 = (ipts[9].volume);
}
if (ipts[10].volume != null ){
var _vol11 = (ipts[10].volume);
}
if (ipts[11].volume != null ){
var _vol12 = (ipts[11].volume);
}

//var _1mute = (ipts[0].muted);
//var _2mute = (ipts[1].muted);
//var _3mute = (ipts[2].muted);
//var _4mute = (ipts[3].muted);
//var _5mute = (ipts[4].muted);
//var _6mute = (ipts[5].muted);
//var _7mute = (ipts[6].muted);
//var _8mute = (ipts[7].muted);
//var _9mute = (ipts[8].muted);
//var _10mute = (ipts[9].muted);
//var _11mute = (ipts[10].muted);
//var _12mute = (ipts[11].muted);



if (ipts[2] != null){
    var _ovly3 = 1;
}
//trace(ovlys[2].value);
//trace(ovlys[0].value);
//trace(ipts[0].state);
//trace(_active);
//trace(_preview);
//trace(_fadeToBlack);
```

Answer (score 1):

To look at each thing in an XML, you do `for (child in xml)`. To have any number of variables, you need to use an array, not var1 through varInfinity.

You didn't post enough code, so I'm guessing here:

```
var varArray = [];
for (child in xml) {
    varArray.push(child.volume);
}
```

That way, it doesn't matter how many variables you have, the code adapts (rather than you adapting by adding var1, var2, etc).

Comment: Here is the complete code I have now. I have them defined into that normal structure, but I am interfacing them into another global variable so I need to redefine them as a variable that gets piped into another program.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but you can't stick them all into an array and pass the array to the other program?

Comment: I am compiling this code in a program called Stencyl. It has blocks for Haxe code integrated into its interface

Comment: I've never used stencyl, but again, can you pass arrays? Can _vol1 be an array that you do something to inside of stencyl?

Comment: The code above works without the if statements, but now that I added the if statements, the code does not work. So regardless of the interfacing between the 2 programs, shouldn't the haxe code be the same? This code works.

    var _vol1 = (ipts[0].volume);
    var _vol2 = (ipts[1].volume);
    var _vol3 = (ipts[2].volume);

But for some reason adding the if statements messes it up.

Comment: Maybe it's not `null`, but rather `undefined` or something. You still haven't answered my original question: *why* are you doing `_vol1`, `_vol2`, `_vol3` and not an array `_vols`? This solves your problem unless stencyl can't handle arrays (it can).

Comment: Without digging more in depth on how Stencyl handles arrays, it seemed easier to define each of the 12 variables manually instead of taking the XML array and passing to a stencyl array and then defining them as single variables.

What doesn't make sense is why the "if" statement makes the variable declaration work. The new if statement stops the app from crashing but now the variables don't get defined.

Comment: You are creating the variable inside the if statement. So if the condition is false, the variable isn't created. Create the variable outside the if, then set its value inside.

What I was saying earlier is that you take the info you want from the XML array and put it into a normal array, then pass that into stencyl.